# How to do an unattended / silent CPAN install / setup

Tags: perl, unattended, cpan, silent

Is there a simple, backward-compatible way to install a Perl module silently using CPAN?

`PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT` doesn't work for older versions that don't detect a default continent; CPAN will just loop at

> Sorry! since you don't have any existing picks, you must make a geographic selection.

See [`CPAN::FirstTime`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHI/perl-5.8.0/lib/CPAN/FirstTime.pm).

It's possible to use a Perl snippet to load CPAN and configure it, but that's verbose and ugly.

Comment: I'm guessing you were trying to get CPAN.pm to work for automation which is challenging since it was aimed at interactive installs.

Comment: Correct. While using distro package management is often preferable, sometimes you're writing tooling that has to run on many different platforms, writing test harnesses, etc, and CPAN is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You should generally prefer to use distribution package mangement for Perl modules on Linux where possible, but sometimes the module you need isn't carried, you're using a different version of perl (maybe via perlbrew), etc. So you need to install with CPAN, and you probably need to automate it for use in Docker, Vagrant, AWS, etc.

There's a dedicated tool for this, cpanminus or [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7042/lib/App/cpanminus.pm). It can be installed directly without needing CPAN already set up, per the docs linked above.

Many distribution package management systems carry cpanminus too.

The wonderful [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) tool knows how to install cpanminus silently into its managed environment with

```
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

so you don't need to mess with `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT`, Perl scripts that `use CPAN` and configure it directly, `expect` scripts, manually creating files in `~/.cpan`, etc.

Once cpanm is installed you can just

```
cpanm install IPC::Run
```

or whatever, and it runs with no fuss.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider:

```
sudo cpan install YAML::XS <<<yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

`sudo apt install cpanminus`

`cpanm -S YAML::XS`